# How To find Distance between Npcs humanoids so they can chase eachother?

Tags: java, lua, game-engine, game-development, roblox

I have a testing studio place where I created Npcs to chase each other and they do that by looping through workspace to find other humanoids besides their own and chasing them. The problem is I use this if statement `(fighter.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X. - closestEnemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X). Magnitude < 3` that when they are close and less than 3 studs away from each other they will damage one another, but when they are even touching each other, no Damage is happening and when I print that equation into output, I get a negative number when they approach from a certain direction. Someone please help! Thank you. Ps. It would be helpful If someone could tell me a good way to find distances between Npcs that work.
`

Comment: Quick note: The Npc on the left will do damage but the one on the right gets negative numbers like - 26 but the other one works fine from the righ and attacks when like 1 - 3 studs away. Im so confused!

Comment: If you're subtracting X values, the result will be negative for one of them.

Comment: What else can I do to find distance betweeen npcs?